# Expectation of the median of a simple random sample

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

If $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is a simple random sample of $Y$, a random variable with symmetric distribution such that $E[Y]=0$, how can I prove that $E[Med(Y_1,...,Y_n)]=E[Med(-Y_1,...,-Y_n)]$ (being $Med(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ the sample median)? can you give me any tip?

Comment: $Y_i$ and $-Y_i$ have the same distribution, so (e.g. using independence) $\mathbf Y$ and $-\mathbf Y$ have the same distribution

Comment: It is still unclear for me, I know that $Med(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is scale invariant and such, but how can I prove that $Med(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ and $-Med(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ are equally distributed?